# QGIS Atlas pages all exporting same extent

Tags: qgis, extents, atlas

I am trying to export multiple map pages from QGIS using Atlas, I am used to doing this in ArcMap using Data Driven Pages so applying similar concepts to the Atlas but all the exported pages are coming out identical in their extent.

I started with an AOI polygon, created a dot grid that covered the AOI, then pointed the atlas' Coverage Layer to the dot grid, figuring that each dot would be the center of a map tile/page.  I checked on "hidden coverage layer" and gave an output as jpeg etc. outputting to separate files.

I get out separate files but each is the same extent.  If I preview the atlas instead of exporting I can cycle through the dots in the grid but the screen extent in the layout never changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I had not checked on the "Controlled by atlas" setting in the item properties of the map item.  Once checked it seems to be working.